# Difference between evaluation metrics and evaluation function in lightgbm

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

Refer to [lightgbm.cv](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#lightgbm.cv), there are two parameters confusing me: `metrics` and `feval`. Based on my little knowledge on gbdt, evaluation metrics and evaluation function are both to compute the loss, such as auc, from a vector of predictions and a vector of true labels.

However, `metrics` and `function` sound like they are handling different tasks .

1. Are they doing the same thing?
2. To be more specific, if I execute `lightgbm.cv(params,metrics='auc', feval='ks')`, will `feval='ks'` override `metrics='auc'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start with, the general notions of `metrics` and `function` are not at all different: from a mathematical viewpoint, a metric *is* a function ([Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))). And although here the notion of metric is more broad, the argument still holds.

More specifically on your question; from the documentation page you have linked:

> - **metrics** (*string, list of strings or None, optional (default=None)*) – Evaluation metrics to be monitored while CV. If not None, the metric in `params` will be overridden.
> - **feval** (*callable or None, optional (default=None)*) – Custom evaluation function.

Notice 1) the plural metric**s**, which can be a *list of strings* 2) the term **custom** in `feval`.

To make a long story short:

1. You can indeed use more than one available metrics in the `metrics` argument; your example should be:

   ```
   lightgbm.cv(params,metrics=['auc','ks'])
   ```
2. `feval` should only be used if, *additionally* to whatever `metrics` you may use from the readily available ones, you also want a *custom* metric you have defined yourself; see an example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1230), where `metric='auc'` and `feval = my_err_rate` are used simultaneously and after `my_err_rate` has been defined.